# how convert a java project to maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to convert to Maven a lot of java projects. I've tried to do: **Right click on my project --> Configure --> Convert to Maven Project.** but I only get: pom.xml (I put every depency that I need, plugins and etc).

My pom.xml contains:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>prueba</groupId>
  <artifactId>prueba</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But my java docs appears empty and the following code structure inside:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hmj4.jpg)

[Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWk7m.jpg)

But as you can see, it doesn't work because I don't have my original java code in "Maven format" and it doesn't build anything in the test.

How could I convert every java file to Maven to can execute in my TestNG.xml??

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your dependencies are not resolved or the project is not built.

Can you right click on your pom.xml and run maven install. Is your build successfull ?

Once your build is successfull.

Can you right click on project -> Maven -> Update project -> Check the Force update of snapshots/releases.

This will get all the dependencies in your classpath.

Build the code again and then it should work.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Hi @Saurav thanks for your help. I've donde what you said: run maven install on pom.xml and the build was successfull. Then, I updated project from Maven menu, but I don't get anything new. I still havethe same structure than before. I don't get any testng.xml and my java files don't convert to maven either. What happen?? thanks so much!!

Comment: What do you mean hava files don't convert to maven ?....what do you expect the pom to do ?...can you please post your pom.xml file ?

Comment: I have two java files that I want to execute (one after other), this way I am not be able to execute any files.
My pom.xml contents the following (I post it in my answer).